# Ansible: how to get output to display

Tags: ansible

I have the following playbook, [Playbook with output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IIAT.png)

There are currently no errors and it runs fine. However, it does not display the output to the console. I have come across this with other playbooks and got around it by adding the following task to the playbook:

```
-debug: var=output.stdout_lines
```

and it prints the output. However, I tried to do the same thing in the
above playbook and it says that the variable was undefined (code not
shown because it didn't work).

Is anyone aware of a better way to get the output to print to the console without using `-debug`? Any ansible references would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use -v when running ansible-playbook.

Comment: You probably cannot omit the space in your debug line.  Should be: `- debug: ...`

Comment: Note that the duplicate target refers to remote commands, however not all commands will use `stdout_lines`, like the one in this question, hence the duplicate might not answer this question

Answer (score 52):

Every Ansible task when run can save its results into a variable. To do this, you have to specify which variable to save the results into. Do this with the `register` parameter, independently of the module used.

Once you save the results to a variable you can use it later in any of the subsequent tasks. So for example if you want to get the standard output of a specific task you can write the following:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - shell: ls
      register: shell_result

    - debug:
        var: shell_result.stdout_lines
```

Here `register` tells ansible to save the response of the module into the `shell_result` variable, and then we use the `debug` module to print the variable out.

An example run would look like the this:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [command] *****************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "shell_result.stdout_lines": [
        "play.yml"
    ]
}
```

Responses can contain multiple fields. `stdout_lines` is [one of the default fields](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/common_return_values.html) you can expect from a module's response.

Not all fields are available from all modules, for example for a module which doesn't return anything to the standard out you wouldn't expect anything in the `stdout` or `stdout_lines` values, however the `msg` field might be filled in this case. Also there are some modules where you might find something in a non-standard variable, for these you can try to consult the module's documentation for these non-standard return values.

Alternatively you can increase the verbosity level of ansible-playbook. You can choose between different verbosity levels: `-v`, `-vvv` and `-vvvv`. For example when running the playbook with verbosity (`-vvv`) you get this:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [command] *****************************************************************
(...)
changed: [localhost] => {
    "changed": true,
    "cmd": "ls",
    "delta": "0:00:00.007621",
    "end": "2017-02-17 23:04:41.912570",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "ls",
            "_uses_shell": true,
            "chdir": null,
            "creates": null,
            "executable": null,
            "removes": null,
            "warn": true
        },
        "module_name": "command"
    },
    "rc": 0,
    "start": "2017-02-17 23:04:41.904949",
    "stderr": "",
    "stdout": "play.retry\nplay.yml",
    "stdout_lines": [
        "play.retry",
        "play.yml"
    ],
    "warnings": []
}
```

As you can see this will print out the response of each of the modules, and all of the fields available. You can see that the `stdout_lines` is available, and its contents are what we expect.

To answer your main question about the `jenkins_script` module, if you check [its documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/jenkins_script_module.html), you can see that it returns the output in the `output` field, so you might want to try the following:

```
tasks:
  - jenkins_script:
      script: (...)
    register: jenkins_result

  - debug:
      var: jenkins_result.output
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the best answer I've found, even checking the Duplicate question.

Comment: In the above example, how do I debug/print/use the value of _raw_params ... say I want to use the current value set in _raw_params to do another task. I can - debug: var=jenkins_result.result but when I do -debug: var=jenkins_result.result.invocation.module_args._raw_params I get variable undefined.